# How to Remove Garlic Ginger Paste smell from refrigerator

Tags: refrigerator, garlic, smell, ginger

When I put paste of garlic and ginger in the fridge the smell of paste spread in all the fridge and the other things too which are in the fridge.Kindly help me how to get rid of this to avoid the smell spreading in other products

Answer (score 1):

For the future, the only effective way I know of is to seal it doubly. That is, take two containers that promise to be airtight (such as glasslock style containers with gaskets), keep the paste in the inner one, and the inner one in the outer one. I know this is very tedious, but I have not found any other way that works for garlic smells in a fridge. Try using glass or steel containers, since plastic is permeable after some time, and also binds with the smell.

If your fridge stinks now, you have to clean it out thoroughly. Throw out whatever food has taken on the smell, you cannot remove it. Wash the shelves, preferably in a dishwasher at a "pots" cycle. Turn off the refrigerator, wash it with something strong - I suggest 12% hydrogen peroxide, this also kills mold spores if there are any - and let it air for half a day until you return the shelves and food and turn it on again.

Comment: 12% H2O2 may be a bit hard to come by.  The only places I know that routinely carry it in the US are hair-shop supply stores, and it's often stabilized with an acid (sulfuric, IIRC).  Regular old 3% (sold in the brown bottles in the US as antiseptic for wounds), mixed with a little bit of baking soda makes for a fantastic deodorizer.  A good scrub with dish soap and hot water, followed by a soak in 3% H2O2 spiked with bicarb is my go to for odor remover.  (With a little bit of dish soap added in, this even works to remove skunk odor.)

Answer (score 0):

Baking soda has long been used to removed unwanted smells from the refrigerator. Get a small box, open the top, and place the whole box in the fridge.

Comment: -1, this is a persistent myth, but it does not help.

Comment: @rumtscho I think myth might be overstating it. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/does-baking-soda-remove-odors

Comment: Why is it overstating it? The answer you cite confirms that it is not effective.

Comment: @rumtscho it doesn’t say it is completely ineffective; it says its effectiveness is not great. It can be improved by providing more surface area (on a plate for example).

Comment: Well, if that's what people read from that answer, then I should go and downvote it :) But you will see that it only gives a putative mechanism for action from a soda merchant known for aggressive marketing, without any evidence that the mechanism works in practice, and if it does, how often and to what extent. The independent scientist's oppinion is that it can in principle soak up odors, "but not very effectively". There is really no reason to believe this.

Comment: +1 because it works for me, and worked for my parents, and their parents. Even a small amount will work, but do remember to keep changing it every couple of months.